# How do I stop AVFoundation audio from restarting when returning to first ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

Using AVFoundation, I am trying to use background music that the user can toggle on or off. It's set to automatically play the music when the first screen of the app comes up. When switching to another ViewController, such as Settings, the music continues play, which is good. However, when I click the back button to go back to the main screen, the music restarts. I've searched related questions; however, it hasn't seemed to work for me, or they've  been a little different. What I am wanting it to do is that if the music is already playing, it will keep playing instead of restart.

This is what I've got so far:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

var g_musicEffect: AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    //MARK: Actions
    @IBAction func playButton(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "seguePlay", sender: self)
    }
    @IBAction func settingsButton(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueSettings", sender: self)
    }


    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let musicFile = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "electronic", ofType: ".mp3")

        do
        {
            try g_musicEffect = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL (fileURLWithPath: musicFile!))
        }
        catch
        {
            print(error)
        }
            g_musicEffect.play()
            g_musicEffect.numberOfLoops = -1
}
```

Comment: check if on pressing back your main screen viewDidLoad() is getting called. That is the problem.

Comment: are you using unwind segue while coming back to your first view controller ? i.e when back button pressed
With normal segues the view will be loaded once again which is what your actual problem is. Use unwind segue

Comment: do .popViewController(animated: true) in settings screen.

Comment: Using unwind segues fixed the problem. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using unwind segue while coming back to your first view controller ? i.e when back button pressed With normal segues the view will be loaded once again which is what your actual problem is. Use unwind segue.